# How to change CodeLens key bindings in VS 2019?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2019, key-bindings, codelens

I use more than one machine to do programming work in C#/Visual Studio 2019. All is well except the fact that some key bindings are different.

The problem I have is with **CodeLens show references** popup which by default is activated by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> shortcut. However on my other machine the same function is bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> shortcut, which of course is the source of my frequent mistakes when I need to switch.

Obviously I'd prefer to have the same shortcut on both machines. Therefore my question is about possible ways to change key bindings for Codelens show references popup function.

I have been looking at `Options -> Environment -> Keyboard` in Visual Studio settings but could not find anything even remotely related to CodeLens show references popup feature.

Any suggestions how to change that binding?